# Empty CharField with null=True returns NoneType Django 1.8

Tags: django, django-models

As fas as I understand, this CharField must return `null` when it's not filled with data, but instead it returns None.

```
  number_of_likes = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False, null=True)
```

The main issue for me is when I want to incriminate previous value, I get such sort of problem

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

How should I handle it?

```
object.number_of_likes = previus_number_of_likes  + 1
```

Comment: `null` does not exist in Python, None is the value that represents null values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `null` doesn't exist in python, `None` is the way to represent null values. That said, there are several ways you could address your issue:

**Option 1: Change your field definition to:**

```
 number_of_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**Option 2: If you don't want to change the field, you could:**

```
 object.number_of_likes = int(object.number_of_likes) + 1 if object.number_of_likes else 1
```

Hope this helps

Comment: IntegerField does incriminates automatically, right? And I need to incriminate it artificially . Do I better use BigIntegerField here?

Comment: Neither IntegerField nor BigIntegerField increment automatically, you have to do that manually as you were doing. The only difference between IntegerField and BigIntegerField is the size of the number

Answer (score 0):

Just to check I did a `python manage.py shell` and typed

```
>>> null
```

and got:

```
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

I don't think there's a `null`, except when a `None` is stored into the database.

Answer (score 0):

null may not have public availabilty but exists as a property when using models.Integerfield although Django docs has explicitly said that it is best to avoid using it with Charfield - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).